# Using dusk to test livewire forms

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-dusk

I have a bunch of laravel components that contains a lot of fields like:

```
public $last_name;
public $middle_name;
public $title;
public $suffix;
public $home_email;
```

I have them all bound to inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" wire:model.lazy="first_name" />
```

And I'm trying to test with Dusk like:

```
public function testCreatePerson()
{
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->loginAs(User::find(1))
            ->visit('/person/create')
            ->type('first_name','Test')
            //...
```

But I keep getting failed tests because fields will randomly be empty. I think it has to with livewire binding timings.  I've tried adding pauses of different lengths and they work sometimes but not always. Why does this happen and what is the solution. Both Dusk and Livewire are the way the Laravel community has gone, and Livewire's own tests are supposedly Dusk tests, so what am I missing that I can't test these forms this way?

Answer (score 1):

I know this i getting a little old, but here is my take and i hope it can help others.

I've had similar issue myself. I think you are right it has something to do with the livewire binding. I fixed mine by using **typeSlowly** instead of **type**.

My issue was that input field was not completely finished with updating the property in the livewire component, before submitting the values to a save method.

You may also want a pause before you submit anything in your form, if typeSlowly doesn't work.

Dusk documentation for this:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#typing-values

So your code would look something like this:

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $browser->loginAs(User::find(1))
        ->visit('/person/create')
        ->typeSlowly('first_name','Test')
```

Answer (score 1):

After many hours, this worked for me; my fields have input masks; I'm also using a [dusk selector](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk#dusk-selectors):

```
$browser->visit($url)
    ->click('@dusk_selector')
    ->keys(@dusk_selector', 'Test')
    ->pause($this->pause_fade);
```

This key is that you click into the input field and then use keystrokes.

The pause may be necessary depending on your next step.  I set a property like $pause_fade=200, and use it in case i need to increase or decrease all of them.  The purpose is to wait for the server to come back with the validated livewire response and update the DOM.

The input field would look like:

```
<input dusk='dusk_selector' />
```